# Cannot get mocks working with Vitest with a simple Node and Typescript setup

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, vite, vitest

Following the documentation cheat sheet, but cannot get the mocks working with Vitest.

I have a simple file where I export some functions. I want to test a function which calls another function within the same file. Since this is a unit test, I want to mock the later.

Here is the setup

```
import { afterEach, it, describe, expect, vi, Vitest, Mock } from 'vitest';
import { logErrorWithApi, handleError } from "../../../src/functions/inqueue/queue-menu.protected";

vi.mock('../../../src/functions/inqueue/queue-menu.protected', async () => {
    const original = await vi.importActual<typeof import('../../../src/functions/inqueue/queue-menu.protected')>('../../../src/functions/inqueue/queue-menu.protected');
    return {
        ...original,
        logErrorWithApi: vi.fn(),
    }
});

describe(getDescribeName(__filename), () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        vi.resetAllMocks();
    });

    describe('handleError', () => {
        it('should call logErrorWithApi with correct params', async () => {
            const errorMock = new Error('Test error');
            const contextMock = { ctx: 'test'};
            const tagsMock = ['tag1', 'tag2'];

            await handleError(errorMock, contextMock, tagsMock);

            expect(logErrorWithApi).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                ...contextMock,
                message: 'Test error | stack: ' + errorMock.stack
            },
            ['queue-menu', 'tag1', 'tag2']);
        });
    });
});
```

I added some logs in the actual `logErrorWithApi` function, and it is always being called. So, I get zero # calls for the mock and the test fails.

I mostly followed this cheat sheet: https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#cheat-sheet also tried doing this with `spyOn` method and providing an implementation. Didn't work.

I am also wondering if this could be a typescript config issue if it's not being compiled into a form that vitest could use. Here is my typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "ES2017",                       
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                           
    "moduleResolution": "node",     
    "types": ["vitest/globals"],                            
     "resolveJsonModule": true,           
    
    /* JavaScript Support */
     "allowJs": true,                         

    /* Emit */
     "outDir": "./build",                            

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": false,
    
    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```